# Azure Function key disappears

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App and created a new host key. This new host key was created manually.
On the Azure Data Factory pipeline, I have the Function App activity, connected to this Function App.
On the Linked Service I put the value of the function key I created manually and Authentication method as System Assigned Managed Identity.

When I run the pipeline the first time, it runs successfully. When I try to run it again, it fails, and if I go to my Azure Function App, my manually created function is  disappeared.

I have tried to go through the documentations, but there is no such information about this.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Tried to recreate the key, but same issue.

Comment: Looks like your function app is corrupted, did you tried to create a new and tried it?

Comment: I can try that, but what do you mean my function app is corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Function key disappears

I have tried to reproduce in my environment and got expected results:

ADF Design:

[image]

Runs:

[image]

AFAIK, I guess the problem is with your Function App(it may have been corrupted which means the configuration might be wrong, maybe an error or dysfunctionality got while it got created, may be an internet interruption while creation), You can check function app logs their you can find the issue of it.

I would suggest you create a new function app and try, If still the issue persists I would suggest you to raise a support request.

Comment: I recreated the function, and after several successful runs, the master key did not change. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Gald @f_to, It worked Out for you.